# Execute a Perl program in a subdirectory?

Tags: perl, bash

Here's my project:

```
assembler/
    asm.pl               # Main entry point
    instructions.pm
    support.pm
build.sh

---- assembler/asm.pl ----
...
use instructions;
...

---- assembler/instructions.pm ----
...
use support;
...
```

I wish for `build.sh` to contain a line like:

```
perl assembler/asm.pl $1
```

When `asm.pl` tries to use the related modules, it can't find them. This line works, but feels filthy and shameful:

```
cd assembler; perl asm.pl ../$1; cd ..
```

What is the correct way to execute `asm.pl`? I wish to execute the program located anywhere on the file system directly from any other arbitrary location, e.g.

```
$ cd /some/dumb/path
$ /path/to/the/project/build.sh /another/goofy/path.asm
```

Comment: Does it work for your use case if you use the `-I` option, e.g. `perl -I assembler` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is that perl is trying to find the libraries relative to the path you're executing from. That's why running cd first fixes it. Your other option is to tell perl where it might find the files. You can do this using the PERL5LIB environmental variable or with the -I switch. This should do it:

```
perl -I./assmbler/ assembler/asm.pl $1
```